# How to create two of the same objects but in different states

Tags: java, eclipse, slick2d

I am trying to create at least two independent objects using the same class. Meaning that I want each of them to use the same class but use the variables in it independently. I am not sure if this is possible but that is why I am here.

The two skeletons (skeleton1 and skeleton2) are the two objects that I want to be independent of each other.

```
@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame gm, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException {

    background.draw(0, 0, Constants.WIN_WIDTH, Constants.WIN_HEIGHT);

    g.drawImage(ccb, mkX, mkY);

    Skeleton skeleton1 = new Skeleton(g, gm);
    Skeleton skeleton2 = new Skeleton(g, gm);

    score = new DeathScreenButton(scoreCounter, (Constants.WIN_WIDTH / 2) / 2, 0, g, Color.transparent);

}
```

More specifically, I want their x and y axis to be independent shown here (they are sX and sY):

```
public class Skeleton {

private Graphics g;
private StateBasedGame gm;

private int mkX = InGame.getmkX();
private int mkY = InGame.getmkY();

// This makes them spawn on each other :(
// "static" prevents them from popping around the screen
private static int sX = (int)(Math.random() * Constants.WIN_WIDTH) + 1;
private static int sY = (int)(Math.random() * Constants.WIN_HEIGHT) + 1;

private Image skele;

public Skeleton (Graphics g, StateBasedGame gm) {

    this.g = g;
    this.gm = gm;

    try {
        init();
    } catch (SlickException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    render();

    try {
        update();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to learn what `static` means, basically. If the two separate objects should have separate `sX` and `sY` variables, they shouldn't be static. We don't really know why you've made them static - what you mean by "popping around the screen" - but that's the problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to explain that. If it is not marked as static every time the game updates sX and sY will choose a new random location to spawn the skeleton at.
Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: No, it really won't. Those are just *initializers* which would be invoked each time you create a new `Skeleton` instance. You need to go back and look at that aspect more carefully, as that's the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Skeletons are independent already.
One of Objected-Oriented programming purposes are class instances. This way, two instances of the same class may have the same attributes, but they will **never be the same**.
It may be a little confusing in the beginning, but the objective is to develop reusable code, then you may instantiate 1..n Skeletons, and they will be independent.

```
Skeleton skel1 = new Skeleton(Graphics g, StateBasedGame gm);
```

Hope it was helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Write/Overwrite the `update` method, if you haven't already. Update your positions in that method.

Put the initialization of the variables `sX` and `sY` in the constructor.

Remove `static`. By marking `sX` and `sY` `static`, all instances of your class will always share these values, so you can never have to Skeletons with different coordinates. If you change the value for one instance, you change it for all instances.

> same class but use the variables in it independently

That basically means: I want to use instance variables. Variables marked `static` are *class* variables.

Comment: Sorry for the rookie response but how do you mean in the constructor? When I did that the two variables were no longer recognized by the other methods that need those two variables. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Like this: http://pastebin.com/R7yV3yBG  You can then no longer access the variables in a static way (e.g. Skeleton.sY), but you have to define getters as in the example.

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much. What if I had to add to sX such as here:
http://pastebin.com/ieygmVkW

Comment: Just as you do `skele.getWidth()`, you'd do `skele.getSX()`